# Windows 7 desktop: forcing new icons (e.g. after starting a download) to appear last?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, windows-explorer

Before I begin, this issue is a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/207137/windows-7-desktop-icons-new-icon-placement) and I am aware of that. But because two  years has gone by and nobody else has asked since then, I figured there may have been developments.

As in the above question, I want to make new icons on my desktop appear at the bottom of the existing icon list. They currently appear under "Computer" on the top left which is annoying. I have tried various sorting options and *do* have *Auto-arrange icons* turned on because I like its functionality.

This issue didn't ever happen in XP - new icons always appeared at the "bottom right" or last position after all the existing icons.

P.S. I would not like to use third party apps such as "Fences" and am just looking to configure Windows to (hopefully natively) do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Leave Auto-Arrange turned off, but Align-to-Grid turned on. This way you can manually set your icons to where you want them and they will remain locked into that grid position. If you add a new icon, e.g. create a new shortcut, if it doesn't place it where you want, just drag it to your desired grid. The only thing that can scramble the arrangement of icons is if you change your display resolution (that's annoying!)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I'm looking to replicate XP's behaviour, which was that every new icon appeared at the bottom of the list even with Auto-Arrange on. I don't think W7 has this feature after all. :(